# how to display textview to right side in tablerow in android

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

i am developing an android app. i need to display textview at right side in tablerow, below is the code i am using, what is wrong with this code???

```
ScrollView src;
src=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

TableLayout t1=new TableLayout(context);

TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);                        
tableRowParams.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    TableRow tr=new TableRow(context);
    TextView txt_peron_name=new TextView(context);
    txt_peron_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt_peron_name.setTextSize(15);
    txt_peron_name.setText("Hello");
    //txt_peron_name.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
    tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cc1);
    //tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
    tr.addView(txt_peron_name);
    t1.addView(tr,tableRowParams);

}// End of For Loop
src.removeAllViews();   

src.addView(t1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this code.

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(StackDemosActivity.this);
TableLayout t1 = new TableLayout(StackDemosActivity.this);

TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
tableRowParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(StackDemosActivity.this);
    TextView txt_peron_name = new TextView(StackDemosActivity.this);
    txt_peron_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt_peron_name.setTextSize(15);
    txt_peron_name.setText("Hello");
    tr.addView(txt_peron_name);
    tr.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    t1.addView(tr, tableRowParams);
}// End of For Loop
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
ll.removeAllViews();
sv.addView(t1);
ll.addView(sv);
```

I changed some code like taking LinearLayout then adding ScrollView inside. So this was minor changes I have made.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assign gravity right to your text view in your XML.

OR Programmatically

`txt_peron_name.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

try this also

`txt_peron_name.setLayoutParams(this.rowParams);`//Layout params of your row

Comment: this is not working. i am displaying tableLayout dynamically and addding row in it, and i want textview txt_person_name to display at right side of the row. how can i?

Comment: @HiteshKamani, After adding gru's suggestion, code is running fine with right gravity. You should check your code. I have implemented and working fine.

Comment: @ChintanRathod, i am stucked. can you post your code here you implemented??

Comment: try this I think you didnt specify layout params for your text view

Answer (score 0):

@Hitesh Kamani
try this

```
TextView ta  = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.text_view);
       LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
       lp.gravity= Gravity.RIGHT; 
 ta.setLayoutParams(lp);
```